# Sinatra programatically get port and other information about service

Tags: ruby, web-services, sinatra

I have a sinatra service  foo.rb

To run it I on a different port I would type  "ruby foo.rb -p 5000".

While the program is running I would like to be able to get the port (in this case 5000) and other information.   Is there a way to get info like this while the app is running?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to get to it with `settings.port` in any Sinatra action.

See [this page](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html) for a list of all the built-in settings.

Comment: This is correct, but I did not ask the question as clearly as I should have.  I really needed the port from within a Sinatra::Base object.  I have posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932750/from-sinatra-base-object-get-port-of-application-including-the-base-object

Thanks for this answer though!