# From Sinatra Base object. Get port of application including the base object

Tags: ruby, web-services, sinatra

I have a Sinatra::Base object that I would like to include in all of my web apps.  In that base class I have the configure method which is called on start-up.

I would like that configure code to 'register' that service with a centralized database. The information that needs to be sent when registering is the information on how to contact this web-service... things like host and port.

I then plan on having a monitoring service that will spin over all registered services and occasionally ping them to make sure they are still up and running.

In the configure method I am having trouble getting the port information.  The 'self.settings.port' variable doesn't seem to work in this method.

a) any ideas on how to get the port? I have the host.

b) is there a sinatra plug-in that already does something like this so I don't have to write it myself? :-)

> //in my Sinatra::Base code.  lets call it register_me.rb
>
> RegisterMe < Sinatra::Base
>
> configure do
>
> //save host and port information to database
>
> end
>
> get '/check_status'
>
> //return status
>
> end
>
> ---
>
> //in my web service code
>
> require register_me  //at this point, sinatra will initialize the RegisterMe object and call configure
>
> post ('/blah')
>
> //example of a method for this particular web service
>
> end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sinatra::Application.port  will return the correct port